# C# Import Excel Table

Tags: c#, excel

Code:
http://hastebin.com/epegomigus.avrasm

I want to import a Excel.
It  gives me an error in loadExcel() in try catch block.

> Error: Syntaxerror in FROM-Klausel.

Comment: there is a square bracket after your table name: 'Sheet1]' <--

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks essential information (it contains no code at all - external links to code are discouraged on SO)

Answer (score 0):

You missing a square bracket:

Change this line:

```
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Sheet1]", conn);
```

To:

```
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", conn);
```

Thank you